# Can overriding be an effective replacement for an if statement in lazy initialization and in general?

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance, overriding, oop

I'm trying to mimic the following abstract class, designed to enable only one lazy initialization, without using logic statements. I'm ignoring the synchronization elements necessary for thread safety for simplicity's sake.

```
abstract class Thunk<T>
{
    private boolean initiated = false;
    private T value;

    public T get()
    {
        if(!initiated) // not using (value == null)
        {
            value = compute();
            initiated = true;
        }

        return value;
    }

    abstract protected T compute();
}
```

Can an instance of the following abstract class be hacked by a child to initialize the same variable more than once?

```
abstract class Thunk<T>
{
    private T value;
    private Computer<T> computer;

    public Thunk()
    {
        computer = new Computer<T>(this);
    }

    public T get()
    {
        value = computer.getValue();    
        return value;
    }

    abstract protected T compute();

    private class Computer<T> 
    {
        private static final String TAG = "Computer";

        private Thunk<T> thunk;
        private T value;
        private Computer<T> computer;

        public Computer(Thunk<T> thunk)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "constructed");
            this.thunk = thunk;
            computer = this;
        }

        public T getValue() 
        {
            Log.d(TAG + ".getValue()", "");
            value = computer.computeValue();
            return value;
        }

        protected T computeValue() 
        {
            Log.d(TAG + ".computeValue()", "");
            value = thunk.compute();
            computer = new DumbComputer<T>(thunk, value);
            return value;
        }

        //this is for maximal encapsulation
        private class DumbComputer<T> extends Computer<T>
        {
            private static final String TAG = "DumbComputer";
            private T value;

            public DumbComputer(Thunk<T> thunk, T value) 
            {
                super(thunk);
                Log.d(TAG + ".contructed()", "booki");
                this.value = value; 
            }

            //overriding so that value will be calculated only once.
            @Override
            protected T computeValue() 
            {
                Log.d(TAG + ".computeValue()", "");
                return value;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. Perhaps write a summary of the question in addition to the code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by overriding the `get` method.

To fix that you can make the `get` into a `final` method. That will prevent overriding and give you singleton-like behaviour.

Note that the code you have written is not thread safe.

You could achieve thread safety by making the method `synchronized` (don't worry about performance *until* you know you gave a problem and that the method is the hotspot, because slow correct code is better than fast incorrect code, and the JVM is very good at optimising locks. If you find a specific lock for this class to be excessively hot, you can use a number of tricks to speed it up... *but don't worry about that just yet*)

Also worth pointing out the resource holder inner class pattern for lazy init (not applicable to your use case as this class need. It be used for only singletons) can be used if you wan the best lazy init of singletons.

**update (responding to comment as comments don't support formatting)**

Do this:

```
abstract class Thunk<T>
{
    private boolean initiated = false;
    private T value;

    public synchronized final T get()
    {
        if(!initiated) // not using (value == null)
        {
            value = compute();
            initiated = true;
        }

        return value;
    }

    abstract protected T compute();
}
```

That is the simplest code that can possibly work. Don't even dream of trying to "improve" that code. It can be improved, but the improvements will differ depending on how the class is being used, and the complexity of the improvement will hide what your code is trying to do. Start with the simplest thing that can work, and go from there.

Keep It Simple Stupid

And don't solve problems you don't have yet

Comment: Can I choose to synchronize(lock) only the contents of the original computeValue() method, in order to save synchronization? which lock should I choose? Do I also have to add volatile statement to the value variable?

Comment: I realize that and concur; readability and simplicity are paramount. I was asked an object oriented question at an interview and was exploring to improve my understanding of polymorphism. Your first answer was very informative.

Comment: If I wanted to be able to lazily initialize and then deflate and initialize again the overriding method would become costlier.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern

```
public final void f() {
    ...
    X x = ...;
    g(x);
    ...
}

abstract protected void g(X x);
```

is quite usefull in contractual programming:

- to impose a behaviour (body of f), and
- to provide a local context (x).

A behaviour often is realized by holding a state (like your `initiated`).
So yes, it is fine for lazy evaluation. Though lazy evaluation can be achieved on field level, for instance by the seldom seen jewel `Future<>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example does not work as (probably) intended, as you create a new `DumbComputer` each time you call `Thunk.get`. You can achieve your goal as follows (but I do not think it's good design, and I *really* do not see where the advantage compared to an easier solution shuld be):

```
abstract class Thunk<T> {

    T value;
    Computer<T> computer;

    protected abstract T doCompute ();

    private interface Computer<T> {
        Computer getComputer ();
        T compute ();
    }

    public Thunk<T> () {
        // initialize computer with a calculating one
        computer = new Computer<T> () {
            Computer getComputer () {
                // return a dumb computer
                return new Computer<T> () {
                    Computer getComputer () { return this; }
                    T compute () { return value; }
                }
            }
            T compute () { value = doCompute (); return value; }
        };
    }

    public T getValue () {
        T v = computer.compute (); computer = computer.getComputer (); return v;
    }
}
```